# Missing return value in javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-maps-api-3

I have a function to return which of two points is closer to a third point:

```
//returns true if address1 is closer to address0 than address2
function closer(address0,address1,address2) {
    console.log(getDistance(address0,address2) + "fun from closer")
    var d1 = getDistance(address0,address2)
    console.log(address0+" "+address2+" "+d1)
    var d2 = getDistance(address0,address1)
    console.log(address0+" "+address1+" "+d1)
    return (d1 > d2);
}
```

which uses another function which uses google maps api to calculate distance between two points:

```
function getDistance(address1, address2) {
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    var request = getRequest(address1,address2);
    directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            console.log(response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value+ " the value");
            return (response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value);
        }
        else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
            return 0;
        }
  });
```

And this is the log from the browser:

```
undefinedfun from closer
11 Franklin Ave, Franklin Square, NY 11010, USA 11 Franklin Ave, Franklin Square, NY 11010, USA undefined
11 Franklin Ave, Franklin Square, NY 11010, USA grand canyon    undefined
0 the value
3906002 the value
```

Which indicates that while the value is present in the getDistance function for some reason it doens't make it to the closer function. Any ideas?

I did notice that the log is sort of "out of order", since the console logs in getDistance should really be before the console logs in closer, but I don't know if that means anything, all the more so what to do about it.

Comment: You need a return value for getDistance and not handlers of directionsService.  Since you don't return any value now getDistance returns undefined.

Comment: doesn't return (response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value); serve that purpose?

Comment: No, the handler for directionsService.route is taken to the nextTick. In other words its a different flow which executes only after the maps api returns. Do you happen to use promises ? That would resolve this situation or you might need to use callbacks. I will write something in answers sections.

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this works for you:

```
function closer(address0, address1, address2, callback) {
    console.log(getDistance(address0, address2) + "fun from closer")
    var d1, d2;
    getDistance(address0, address2, function(d) {
        d1 = d;
        consolidate();
    });
    getDistance(address0, address1, function(d) {
        d2 = d;
        consolidate();
    });
    function consolidate() {
        if(d1 && d2) {
            callback(d1 > d2);
        }
    }
}

function getDistance(address1, address2, cb) {
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    var request = getRequest(address1, address2);
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            return (response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value);
        } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
            return 0; //may be you don't want to return 0 here since you are comparing distances.
        }
    });

//usage:

closer(address0, address1, address2, function(status) {
    console.log(status);
});
```

This solution does  not use promises. With promises it will be mighty easier.

Comment: I wouldn't mind using promises, but if you incorporate them please add some explanation as I am quite unfamiliar.

Answer (score 0):

With promises

```
//add <script> tag for a source downloaded from here https://github.com//kriskowal/q

function closer(address0, address1, address2) {
    var d = Q.defer();
    Q.allSettled([getDistance(address0, address1), getDistance(address0, address2)], function(results) {
        if(results[0].state === 'fulfilled' && results[1].state === 'fulfilled') {
            d.resolve(results[0].value > results[1].value);
        }
        else {
            d.reject();
        }
    });
    return d.promise;
}

function getDistance(address1, address2) {
    var d = Q.defer();
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    var request = getRequest(address1, address2);
    directionsService.route (request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            d.resolve(response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value);
        } else {
            //may be you don't want to return 0 here since you are comparing distances.
            d.reject();
        }
    });
    return d.promise;
}
//usage

closer(address0, address1, address2).then(function(status) {
    //status == true is d1
    //status == false is d2
    console.log(status);
}, function(){
    console.log('Could not determined');
});
```

Comment: what do you mean //add <script> tag for a source downloaded from here https://github.com//kriskowal/q? Could you provide specific code for that? Thanks.

Comment: download the source from above url and include it in your html script tags. Like how you normally add a script file to your html. It should look like: <script src="_path_to_your_source_" type="text/javascript" >  </script>